# bash - in for loop, output command to file AND set variable

Tags: bash

Is it possible to output the result of a command to a file AND set a variable, all in the same command?

The following will append the output to a file, but wont set var.

```
for i in myarray; do
    var=$(command >> file)
done
```

Not sure if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will send the output to `file` as well as set `var`:

```
var=$(command | tee -a file)
```

This works because `tee` duplicates the output of `command`.  One copy is appended to `file` while the other copy is sent to stdout.  Command substitution, `$(...)`, captures that stdout and saves it in `var`.